# Will startService() still work if my app targeting nougat devices

Tags: android, performance, android-location, android-8.0-oreo

This is how i start Location service.

```
private void initLocationService() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(getPermissions(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,GET_LOCATION_PERMISSION)){
        startService(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LocationUpdateService.class));
    }
}
```

and in `LocationUpdateService`, i start it as `STICKY` service. So it keeps working in the background.

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        IServiceResponse {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

As my app is currently targeting `Api 25` `(Nougat)`, what changes do i need to make in this particular service to make this work in `Oreo`

I still don't have access to `startForegroundService()` method when using `compileSdkVersion 25`.

These are my `gradle` settings.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
```

Comment: check this link u need to create a channel for the Oreo because service is not working in background  in Oreo.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) is available form API level 26 **NOT** from `API level 25`.

Change `compileSdkVersion 25` and `buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"` to latest it and try.

For example, in my case I am using below:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Comment: Yes after changing `compileSdkVersion` to `27` its giving me the method, but what can go wrong if i don't use `startForegroundService()`, will it crash my app, or `START_STICKY` will stop working.

Comment: and will this change make everything work smoother? 
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        startForegroundService(start_intent);
}`

Comment: Yes correct, you app will crash when it will run. So yes this check will work `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { startForegroundService(start_intent); }`

Comment: Thanks, do you know when google launched these guidelines?

Comment: I think there is no need of guideline for it. It is common Android coding practice to check and support previous version.